# make _children not selectable in data tree - Tabulator React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview, jsx, tabulator

I need parent rows to be selectable and disable selection for child rows. I am using selectable rows with tick box `formatter` option for row selection. I tried using `selectableCheck` but it's not working with the tick `formatter`.

Any help would be appreciated to achieve the same.
Please find the similar code box link: I want to disable row selection checkbox for the child element.

[Codebox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tabulator-examples-fi74j)

I am attaching the sample format that I need.
[image]

**JSX**

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        align: "center",
        headerSort: false,
        cellClick: function(e, cell) {
          cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
          console.log(cell.getRow(), cell.getRow().getTreeParent());
        }
      },
      { title: "Name", field: "name", width: 200 },
      { title: "Location", field: "location", width: 150 },
      { title: "Gender", field: "gender", width: 150 },
      { title: "Favourite Color", field: "col", width: 150 },
      {
        title: "Date Of Birth",
        field: "dob",
        align: "center",
        sorter: "date",
        width: 150
      }
    ];

    let data = [
      {
        name: "Oli Bob",
        location: "United Kingdom",
        gender: "male",
        col: "red",
        dob: "14/04/1984",
        _children: [
          {
            name: "Mary May",
            location: "Germany",
            gender: "female",
            col: "blue",
            dob: "14/05/1982"
          },
          {
            name: "Brendon Philips",
            location: "USA",
            gender: "male",
            col: "orange",
            dob: "01/08/1980",
            _children: [
              {
                name: "Margret Marmajuke",
                location: "Canada",
                gender: "female",
                col: "yellow",
                dob: "31/01/1999"
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "James Newman",
        location: "Japan",
        gender: "male",
        col: "red",
        dob: "22/03/1998"
      }
    ];

    let options = {
      layout: "fitColumns",
      dataTree: true,
      dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
      dataTreeElementColumn: "name"
    };

    return (
      <ReactTabulator
        ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)}
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        tooltips={true}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: show your code?

Comment: @blueseal I have added above the codebox link

Answer (score 2):

I have not explored `react-tabulator`'s API (because of my time constraint) but what I have noticed that
`cell.getRow().getTreeParent()` returns `false` if the selected node has no parent. So, based on that you need to return the `cell.getRow().toggleSelect()`.

[image: GIF]
Is that what you wanted to achieve? Let me know.

```
 cellClick: (e, cell) => {
      // console.log("obj: ", cell.getRow()._row.data);
      // console.log("getTreeParent: ", cell.getRow().getTreeParent());
      // if (cell.getRow()._row.data.hasOwnProperty("_children")) {
      //   return cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
      // }
      console.log("does this Row have children ? ", cell.getRow().getTreeParent());
      if (!cell.getRow().getTreeParent()) {
        return cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
      }
    }
```

Side note: [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#:~:targetText=The%20hasOwnProperty()%20method%20returns,as%20opposed%20to%20inheriting%20it).)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help***This is exactly what I wanted to achieve***. One more ask, is there any way we can hide the checkbox tick selector for children node? Right now the user might also select the children by clicking the check box tick selector. Not all the user will select the row by clicking on the cell If i am not wrong in asking this. -Shalini

Comment: You are right. As per my guess, you need the same logic, you need to return only desired checkbox. You need to find the right attribute and apply the same logic. Like in this case, `cellClick` is the right attribute for allowing a user to click a desired row. If I get time, I will explore their API just to find that attribute.

Comment: Let me know if you find that right attribute for rendering the desired checkboxes. :)

Comment: I couldn't find the attribute so I have written a custom formatter overriding their rowSelection formatter. Posted the custom Formatter code.

Answer (score 1):

Custom [`formatter`](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/format#format-custom) to enable `rowSelection` only for Parents.

```
{
        formatter: function(cell) {
          //cell - the cell component
          if (cell.getRow().getTreeParent()) {
            return;
          } else {
            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

            checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
            if (this.table.modExists('selectRow', true)) {
              checkbox.addEventListener('click', e => {
                e.stopPropagation();
              });

              if (typeof cell.getRow == 'function') {
                var row = cell.getRow();

                checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
                  row.toggleSelect();
                });
                checkbox.checked = row.isSelected();
                this.table.modules.selectRow.registerRowSelectCheckbox(
                  row,
                  checkbox,
                );
              } else {
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
                  if (this.table.modules.selectRow.selectedRows.length) {
                    this.table.deselectRow();
                  } else {
                    this.table.selectRow();
                  }
                });

                this.table.modules.selectRow.registerHeaderSelectCheckbox(
                  checkbox,
                );
              }
            }
            return checkbox;
          }
        },
        titleFormatter: 'rowSelection',
        align: 'center',
        headerSort: false,
        width: '5px',
        cellClick: function(e, cell) {
          if (!cell.getRow().getTreeParent()) {
            return cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
          }
        },
      },
```

Note:  `document.createElement` will cause performance issue in react because it interacts with real DOM. If you want to  access DOM, then please check out [`Refs and the DOM`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: is this not create performance issue in react, since you are using `document.createElement` and manipulating the DOM?

Comment: I was just checking `ReactTabulator`, most of their `props`  are not getting triggered

Comment: @blueseal I haven't tested with larger dataset. Right now I am not seeing anything weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Selection Elegibility Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/select#setup-eligible) to determine whether a row can be selected or not.

So you can use the ***selectableCheck*** callback and check if the row has a parent to see if it should be selectable

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    selectableCheck:function(row){
        //row - row component
        return !row.getTreeParent(); //only allow selection if the row has no parent
    },
});
```